# Source file 'Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs' could not be found

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

When running `Visual Studio 2010` I attempt to build, but the build fails with the following error:

> **error CS2001**: Source file '*Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs*' could not be found

I have created Windows applications, but in different solutions and I cannot find a reference to this file in the solution/project.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

This rings a bell. I came across a similar problem in the past,

- if you expand Properties folder of the project can you see 'AssemblyInfo.cs' if not that is where the problem is. An assembly info file consists of all of the build options for the project, including version, company name, GUID, compilers options....etc

You can generate an assemblyInfo.cs by right clicking the project and chosing properties. In the application tab fill in the details and press save, this will generate the assemblyInfo.cs file for you. If you build your project after that, it should work.

**Update 2016-07-08**:

For Visual Studio 2010 through the most recent version (2015 at time of writing), LandedGently's comment still applies:

> After you select project Properties and the Application tab as @Tarun mentioned, there is a button "Assembly Information..." which opens another dialog. You need to at least fill in the Title here. VS will add the GUID and versions, but if the title is empty, it will not create the AssemblyInfo.cs file.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2010, after you select project properties and the Application tab as @Tarun mentioned, there is a button "Assembly Information..." which opens another dialog.  You need to at least fill in the Title here.  VS will add the GUID and versions, but if the title is empty, it will not create the assemblyInfo.cs file.

Comment: This can happen -- with saving a new Properties file not even working -- if the Properties folder gets deleted/moved somehow.  I accidentally dragged the Properties folder away to a different location somehow, must bumped the mouse or something... and it was very confusing at first to figure out why all of a sudden it didn't like the properties on a project that was just fine a moment ago!

Comment: When I try this, I get "The property could not be read/written because the language service returned an unknown error".

Comment: Don't forget to expand the Properties node of your project to find AssemblyInfo.cs

Comment: When I try to open properties I get - An error occured while loading the project properties editor.

Answer (score 18):

Try deleting the `assemeblyinfo.cs` file from project under the properties menu and rebulid the project.

Comment: Rebuilding the project worked for me, but the accepted answer didn't.

Answer (score 4):

Excluding the obj folder from the project (in Visual Studio), that contains the Debug & Release folders will also fix the issue.

Answer (score 3):

This can also happen if you have a solution containing the project open in Visual Studio, then use your source control software to change to an older commit that does not contain that project. Normally, this would be obvious as all the project files would disappear as well. But, if it's a new project with very few or no files at all, it could be puzzling to see that just this one file, `AssemblyInfo.cs`, is missing. And, it's more likely you'd be messing about with an `AssemblyInfo.cs` when a project is new, so might miss that another file or two is also missing.

The cure is to do any of the following:

- Fetch the missing `AssemblyInfo.cs` and any other missing files from another commit, taking care to manage and save your `.csproj` file so the referenced files don't vanish from the project—perhaps by adding and removing a random `.cs` file to cause changes to need to be saved (since visual studio thinks the .csproj file has been saved when it hasn't).
- Close and reopen Visual Studio without saving (if the project file isn't really saved) or remove the project. Removing makes sense if you didn't actually want the project created yet, since it will be created in the later commit.
- Recreate the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file manually. Just copy another project, and change the details, especially the GUID so it matches the one from the `.sln` file.

Answer (score 0):

I got the error using TFS, my AssemblyInfo wasn't mapped in the branch I was working on.

Comment: Thanks. the same issue i faced in VS 2013 with my SP 2013 soln. i went to project properties and saved the info. and the error gone! :-)

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem. You should select Properties, Right-Click, Source Control and Get Specific Version.

Answer (score 0):

In .Net Core you do not have an AssemblyInfo.cs file. You can add one with the Add New Item dialog and set the attribute there in the same way you would do that in the .Net Full Framework and get exactly the same benefits.

[image]

Credit to https://improveandrepeat.com/2019/12/how-to-test-your-internal-classes-in-c/#left-sidebar

Answer (score 0):

I just got this issue and it was that Assemblyinfo was in the gitignore under properties. This needs to be there if you want to use the project with azure pipelines