# Can't view Application property page - E_FAIL / Method Not Implemented

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

In the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio 2012, I right click on my wp8 project and go Properties, and the Application tab shows:

```
An error occurred trying to load the page.
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
```

or

```
An error occurred trying to load the page.
The method or operation is not implemented.
```

Would anyone know how to go about debugging this?

I cannot repro this problem with a fresh project, but haven't been able to nail out where it is failing in my project...

Maybe related to AssemblyInfo.cs? [Source file 'Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs' could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494691/source-file-properties-assemblyinfo-cs-could-not-be-found)

BTW it builds and deploys to my device just fine...

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you ought to show us a screenshot of the file structure (expanded) for your project then. If you deleted the AssemblyInfo or any of the manifest files, that's sure to cock things up.

Comment: BTW it compiles and deploys fine to the device...

Comment: For some reason now the error is different... anyways, uploaded a png. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So after an exhaustive round of brute force elimination, I was able to narrow this down to my use of .java files. Yes it is weird, but it has worked. I have been including .java files in my project and setting their properties to Compile as c#. There were merge reasons for doing so, and I had of course modified the java code slightly to compile, but somehow Visual Studio's property pages spaz out when a .java file is included this way, even though the project compiles just fine. So I wrote a little tool to copy all the .java files to .java.cs and include them that way and everything is fine now!

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue in all of my projects and reasoned it might have had to do with a recent Windows update.  I updated VS 2017 to 15.9.15 and that resolved it for me.