# How can I restore a corrupted AssemblyInfo.cs file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, guid, assemblyinfo

I have accidentally copied and replaced more than I should have.... My Guid number ended up changed in the AssemblyInfo.cs file. How can I restore it, not knowing the number it should be?

This has to be a duplicate, but I cant find it.

Comment: Do you have a compiled version of the assembly that used the old Guid anywhere?

Comment: Compiled version yes. Source control no.

Comment: I am unaware of SCCM so probably not.

Comment: If you have a compiled version, you can disassemble it to recover the GUID. Check out ILDASM in the Visual Studio Tools.

Comment: Or use something like ILSpy, Reflector, DotPeek etc to look at the decompiled assembly.

Comment: Is there any harm in using a new guid? (generate in tools, paste generated guid into assembly information.)

Comment: I see you've already done this but figured I'd add a bit of background info. About the only time that GUID is important is if you're exposing your assembly to COM. If you're not exposing it to COM just generate a new one and call it a day.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6494691/19308

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I was able to solve this in a simple way. I figured it out by looking at [this](http://davidmsterling.blogspot.com/2011/05/visual-studio-2010-project-error.html) link. To summarize: in Visual Studio under the tools menu you can generate a guid. If you work out how to do that right it should change the guid in the AssemblyInfo.cs file directly. Then you need to copy the guid to the project properties under Application>Assembly Information. This worked for my simple case. I suspect that it would be more important if it was a part of source control, however at that point you can likely recover it from the submit history.